# What if the linearized gravity equation was the fundamental equation instead of the full Einstein Field Equations?

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle, machs-principle

In Wald's "General Relativity," he discusses two key ideas that motivated Einstein to develop the theory of general relativity:

1. **The Equivalence Principle:** All bodies fall the same way in a gravitational field, suggesting the possibility of ascribing gravitational effects to spacetime's structure. ("All bodies are influenced by gravity and, indeed, all bodies fall precisely the same way in a gravitational field... Perhaps, then, the paths of freely falling bodies are always geodesics, but the spacetime metric is not always that given by special relativity.")
2. **Mach's Principle:** The local structure of spacetime (e.g., "inertial motion" and "nonrotating") should be influenced by the total matter content in the universe. ("In special relativity as in prerelativity notions of spacetime, the structure of spacetime is given once and for all and is unaffected by the material bodies that may be present. In particular, "inertial motion" and "nonrotating" are not influenced by matter in the universe. Mach as well as a number of earlier philosophers and scholars (in particular, Riemann) found this idea unsatisfactory. Rather, Mach felt that all matter in the universe should contribute to the local definition of "nonaccelerating" and "nonrotating"; that in a universe devoid of matter there should be no meaning to these concepts. ")

Given these foundational principles, I have been thinking the following: What if the fundamental equation governing gravitation wasn't $$G_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}$$, but instead the exact formula was the linearized gravity equation $$□h_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{16\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}$$? So, in this hypothetical scenario, what we currently consider a linearized approximation would be the primary equation.

1. In such a hypothetical framework, would the Equivalence Principle inherently remain applicable?
2. How would this hypothetical model align with or reflect Mach's principle?

I'm quite new to GR and have been trying to wrap my head around this. I've consulted various books but haven't understood an answer yet. Any explanations or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The main issue is the conservation of energy-momentum and consistency of the matter equation of motion, which are ruined by the linear coupling to $h_{\mu \nu}$ (in the Lagrangian). The solution is to couple $h_{\mu \nu}$ to itself. This iterative procedure can be shown to end up leading to the full non-linear EFE. Andrew linked the Feynman book where he outlines this argument, also see https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0926

Answer (score 1):

The linearized Einstein equations would not be able to explain observations of non-linear gravity, such as:

- The existence of black holes
- Gravitational waveforms from merging binaries that are consistent with the GR predictions
- Observations of FLRW cosmology, such as the luminosity distance-redshift curves in Type 1a supernovae, the pattern of peaks and troughs in the cosmic microwave background, and Big Bang Nucleosynthesis

Comment: Even Newton gravity predicts black holes, called dark stars. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_star_(Newtonian_mechanics)

Comment: As to the second bullet, the question is if these wave forms are also consistent with the linearised theory

Comment: @my2cts The waveforms are not consistent with Newtonian theory. There are measurements of post-Newtonian parameters up to 3.5 PN order, such as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.03841.pdf.

Comment: @my2cts Also, while historically interesting, it doesn't really makes sense to talk about "dark stars" in Newtonian mechanics because light doesn't have mass. All a dark star is, is an object with an escape velocity equal to the speed of light. The Schwarzschild metric is more than that.

Comment: There are also solar system tests which measure post newtonian parameters, described for example in https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-4.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your answer. Of course, the linearized equation cannot explain many phenomena (precession of Mercury's perihelion, light bending, etc.). But the question is: does the linearized equation violate or not the equivalence and Mach's principles?

Comment: @KennethA In terms of Mach's principle... well, it's actually debatable whether GR even does obey Mach's principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle#Mach's_principle_in_general_relativity. In terms of the equivalence principle... you probably could argue that it does obey the equivalence principle in the same way that Newton's theory of gravitation does. However, linearized gravity coupled to matter fields is not really a fully self-consistent theory, because it doesn't include the gravitational effect of gravitational energy. I'll try to think of a simple argument for this.

Comment: There is a famous argument by Feynman where you start with linearized gravity and then try to guess the non-linear terms in gravity, and by applying various consistency conditions on these non-linear terms you are led to GR, in [the Feynman lectures on gravitation](https://www.amazon.com/Feynman-Lectures-Gravitation-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0813340381/ref=asc_df_0813340381/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=265989256760&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1571367581924939000&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9014962&hvtargid=pla-524519790679&psc=1).

Comment: @Andrew An infinitesimally small mass is enough. If a photon has a mass of $10^-{99} eV/c^2$ it would be attracted in Newton's theory. No one can rule this out. The point of my comments is that the question posed here should not be too lightly discarded.

Comment: @my2cts I don't understand what's deep about this question. Linearized gravity is not a consistent theory if you want gravity to interact with matter, and anyway phenomenologically it's ruled out by observations.